# Node cli flag that will not evaluate code within eval statement

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given the script 'test.js':

```js
console.log(eval('2 + 2'));
```

And the command `node test`, I am looking for a node cli flag with which Node will execute `test.js` but will not evaluate the code within eval.

Comment: I guess you are looking for [`--disallow-code-generation-from-strings`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/cli.html#cli_disallow_code_generation_from_strings)

Comment: I have the exact question in question, the code was with({}){} and the question was how to run the script without actually running the code in it. it has to be a command / flag that can go in the cli.. I figured its just the --check flag.